# Unable to resize and rotate view with setScaleX and setScaleY in onTouch event

Tags: java, android, image, mobile-development

Here I am trying to expand view size with single finger `onTouchevent`. Almost it's working for long length strings but it's not working for small words like "Just" or "Know", complete view is getting shaking, sometimes the view dimensions increasing unexpectedly and the view getting rotating. It would be helpful if some one helps me to correct my code.

Here I am adding my expected output screen image

[image]

**This is TextView:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frmBorder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_tv">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPhotoEditorText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="Burhanuddin"
        tools:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</FrameLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPhotoEditorClose"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top|start"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_remove" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPhotoEditorRotate"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_remove" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**And TouchListener added for imgPhotoEditorRotate**

```
final View textRootView = getLayout(ViewType.TEXT);
final ImageView imgRotate = textRootView.findViewById(R.id.imgPhotoEditorRotate);
SingleTouchListener singleTouchListener= new SingleTouchListener(
                                                textRootView, parentView, this.imageView);
imgRotate.setOnTouchListener(singleTouchListener);
```

**OnTouch Event**

```
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    float x =   event.getX();
    float y =  event.getY();
    float mx = view.getX(); 
    float my =  view.getY();
   switch (action)
   {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           last_x=x;
           last_y=y;
           textRootView.bringToFront();
           break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           float dx = x - last_x;
           float dy = y - last_y;
           updateRotateAndScale(dx, dy,mx,my);
           textRootView.setScaleX(mScale);
           textRootView.setScaleY(mScale);
           float rotation = adjustAngle(textRootView.getRotation() + 
           mRotateAngle);
           textRootView.setRotation(rotation);

           last_x = x;
           last_y = y;
           break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           if (onSingleTouchListener!=null)
           onSingleTouchListener.onRemoveViewListener(view);
           resetView();
           break;
   }
    return  true;
}
public void updateRotateAndScale(final float dx, final float dy, float mx, 
float my) 
{
    float Frame_c_x = textRootView.getPivotX()/2; // frame layout center 
    position, for to perform animation and scale.
    float Frame_c_y = textRootView.getPivotY()/2;

    float x = mx;    // view last x , y position
    float y = my;

    float n_x = x + dx; // extended view
    float n_y = y + dy;

    float xa = x - Frame_c_x; //  Off of the previous view
    float ya = y - Frame_c_y;

    float xb = n_x - Frame_c_x; 
    float yb = n_y - Frame_c_y;

    float srcLen = (float) Math.sqrt(xa * xa + ya * ya);
    float curLen = (float) Math.sqrt(xb * xb + yb * yb);

    float scale = curLen / srcLen; 

    mScale *= scale;
    float newWidth = textRootView.getWidth() * mScale;

    if (newWidth < 70) {
        mScale /= scale;
        return;
    }

    double cos = (xa * xb + ya * yb) / (srcLen * curLen);
    if (cos > 1 || cos < -1)
        return;
    float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(cos));
    float calMatrix = xa * yb - xb * ya;
    int flag = calMatrix > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    angle = flag * angle;

    mRotateAngle += angle;
}
public void resetView() {

    mRotateAngle = 0;
    mScale = 1;

}
```

Comment: And even this is not working for  circle or square shaped images. please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this sample [gist](https://gist.github.com/pskink/92aa3f8d74c15509d5d0b25fd431c008)

Comment: and? do you now know how to do that in your case?

Comment: thanks for your quick response @pskink,
I understood one thing from your referenced url is 
` if (points[3] < getHeight() / 2) {
                matrix.setTranslate(points[6] - points[2], points[7] - points[3]);
            } else {
                matrix.setPolyToPoly(points, 0, points, 4, 2);
            }`
but i didn't understand how i can make my textView as a matrix . could you make it more clear

Comment: you cannot make textView as a matrix - textView is `android.widget.TextView`, matrix is `android.graphics.Matrix`

Comment: could you elaborate your answer please

Comment: just add `setContentView(new Sizer(this) {
            @Override
            protected View getMainView(Context context) {
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.chrome);
                return iv;
            }
        });` in your `Activity#onCreate` method and you will see how it works

Comment: ya i will try with this and i will come back